# How to fix metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: "": must be specified for an update

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, kustomize

So i have this project that i already deployed in GKE and i am trying to make the CI/CD from github action. So i added the workflow file which contains

```
name: Build and Deploy to GKE

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.GKE_PROJECT }}
  GKE_CLUSTER: ${{ secrets.GKE_CLUSTER }}    # Add your cluster name here.
  GKE_ZONE: ${{ secrets.GKE_ZONE }}   # Add your cluster zone here.
  DEPLOYMENT_NAME: ems-app # Add your deployment name here.
  IMAGE: ciputra-ems-backend

jobs:
  setup-build-publish-deploy:
    name: Setup, Build, Publish, and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # Setup gcloud CLI
    - uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@94337306dda8180d967a56932ceb4ddcf01edae7
      with:
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GKE_SA_KEY }}
        project_id: ${{ secrets.GKE_PROJECT }}

    # Configure Docker to use the gcloud command-line tool as a credential
    # helper for authentication
    - run: |-
        gcloud --quiet auth configure-docker

    # Get the GKE credentials so we can deploy to the cluster
    - uses: google-github-actions/get-gke-credentials@fb08709ba27618c31c09e014e1d8364b02e5042e
      with:
        cluster_name: ${{ env.GKE_CLUSTER }}
        location: ${{ env.GKE_ZONE }}
        credentials: ${{ secrets.GKE_SA_KEY }}

    # Build the Docker image
    - name: Build
      run: |-
        docker build \
          --tag "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA" \
          --build-arg GITHUB_SHA="$GITHUB_SHA" \
          --build-arg GITHUB_REF="$GITHUB_REF" \
          .

    # Push the Docker image to Google Container Registry
    - name: Publish
      run: |-
        docker push "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA"

    # Set up kustomize
    - name: Set up Kustomize
      run: |-
        curl -sfLo kustomize https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/releases/download/v3.1.0/kustomize_3.1.0_linux_amd64
        chmod u+x ./kustomize

    # Deploy the Docker image to the GKE cluster
    - name: Deploy
      run: |-
        ./kustomize edit set image LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/REPOSITORY/IMAGE:TAG=$GAR_LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$REPOSITORY/$IMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA
        ./kustomize build . | kubectl apply -k ./
        kubectl rollout status deployment/$DEPLOYMENT_NAME
        kubectl get services -o wide
```

but when the workflow gets to the deploy part, it shows an error

```
The Service "ems-app-service" is invalid: metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: "": must be specified for an update
```

Now i have searched that this is actually not true because the resourceVersion is supposed to change for every update so i just removed it

Here is my kustomization.yaml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - service.yaml
  - deployment.yaml
```

my deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: ems-app
  name: ems-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ems-app
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ems-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/ciputra-nusantara/ems@sha256:70c34c5122039cb7fa877fa440fc4f98b4f037e06c2e0b4be549c4c992bcc86c
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: ems-sha256-1
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

and my service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app: ems-app
  name: ems-app-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.88.10.114
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.88.10.114
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30261
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: ems-app
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 34.143.255.159
```

Comment: Which cluster version are you using?

Comment: i deploy it originally from a dockerfile, i don't create cluster manually with GKE Standard or autopilot if that's what you mean

Comment: Couple of options:
1) remove `clusterIP` from your service spec
2) run `kubectl annotate svcems-app-service kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration-` prior to applying your service update

Comment: This is because there's a **resourceVersion** field in **last-applied-configuration annotation**, which is not expected. Remove the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation by running the command below and update the service again.  

"**kubectl annotate svc my-service kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration-"**         

The - on the end of the annotation tells Kubernetes to remove the annotation entirely.

Comment: i tried both of your suggestions and it works with a little warning, but i searched that it can be ignored, but then i get another problem, which is the changes that i made to files that was build is not there, and i check at the revision details that my revision is not deployed. but then i found that that i set the kustomize set image to repository instead of container image so i change it to this ```./kustomize edit set image gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE:TAG=gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.IMAGE }}:${{  github.sha }}``` but the new revision still hasn't been deployed

Comment: Are you executing the command in the correct folder?

Comment: Thanks @ChandraKiranPasumarti I had same issue " metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: "": must be specified for an update" i used "kubectl annotate svc <service_name> kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration-" and applied my svc.yaml file again and it worked . although it gave warning "Warning: resource services is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation" i ignored it

Comment: @Malik Has your issue been resolved? If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it.

Comment: The solution posted by @ChandraKiranPasumarti works, please add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone still having this problem, I may not be able to help if you still want to use GKE, But you can try the answer from @ChandraKiranPasumarti. For me personally, my senior only require me to containerize our app so I use Google Cloud Run Instead for easier deployments and CI/CD.
You can use this file to use CI/CD in Cloud Run

`https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud/blob/main/example-workflows/cloud-run/cloud-run.yml`

Just make sure you've added secret from service account json in you repo, then select the credentials json for authentication in your yml file

Answer (score 21):

As the title of this question is more Kubernetes related than GCP related, I will answer since I had this same problem using AWS EKS.

`How to fix metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: 0x0: must be specified for an update` is an error that may appear when using `kubectl apply`

`Kubectl apply` makes a [three-way-merge](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/) between your local file, the live kubernetes object manifest and the annotation `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration` in that live object manifest.

So, for some reason, the value `resourceVersion` managed to be written in your `last-applied-configuration`, probably because of someone exporting the live manifests to a file, modifying it, and applying it back again.

When you try to apply your new local file that doesn't have that value -and should not have it-, but the value is present in the `last-applied-configuration`, it thinks it should be removed from thye live manifest and specifically send it in the subsequent `patch` operation like `resourceVersion: null`, which should get rid of it. But it won't work and the local file breakes the rules (out of my knowledge as now) and becomes invalid.

As [feichashao](https://feichashao.com/kubectl-apply-fail/) mentions, the way to solve it is to delete the `last-applied-configuration` annotation and apply again your local file.

Once you did solved, you `kubectl apply` output will be like:

```
Warning: resource <your_resource> is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
```

And your live manifests will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/3657#issuecomment-722706739) github issue I found a better solution for my problem:

It is solved by getting the existing resource version and add it to the update object before applying.

```
    getObj, err := dr.Get(obj.GetName(), metav1.GetOptions{})
    if errors.IsNotFound(err) {
        // This doesnt ever happen even if it is already deleted or not found
        log.Printf("%v not found", obj.GetName())
        return nil, nil
    }

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    obj.SetResourceVersion(getObj.GetResourceVersion())

    response, err := dr.Update(obj, metav1.UpdateOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```